# Does Esperanto use the abbreviations "i.e." and "e.g."?

Tags: translation

Since both *i.e.* and *e.g.* both come from the Latin *id est* and *exempli gratia*, respectively, does Esperanto use the same abbreviations? If not, then what are the Esperanto abbreviations?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Esperanto has its own abbreviations for these:

**i.e.** → *t.e.* = *tio estas*

**e.g.** → *ekz.* = *ekzemple*

Another very common one is:

**etc** → *ktp* = *kaj tiel plu*

There’s [a nice list](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/aldonoj/simboloj_mallongigoj.html) in PMEG.

Answer (score 8):

En Esperanto oni uzas "t.e." (por "tio estas") anstataŭ "i.e.", kaj "ekz" (por "ekzemple") anstataŭ "e.g.".